# How to determine that application is running on internet or intranet using php script

Tags: php

Is any method is available which through we can determine that our current connection is through internet Or intranet using php script.

Thanks.....

Comment: check request origin's IP address

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` variable to obtain if it is `localhost` or other IP address.

Comment: This elaborates on this solution somewhat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818064/check-if-an-ip-address-is-private

Comment: Intranet generally means "from the same LAN as the server", not just "from the same computer as the server"

Answer (score 1):

You could check $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] against $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
If the first number of the IP is the same
and is 192,172,10 or 127 then it is most likely an intranet page.

like this:

```
function is_intranet() {
  $serverIP = explode('.',$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);
  $localIP  = explode('.',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  return ( 
    ($serverIP[0] == $localIP[0]) && 
    (in_array($serverIP[0],array('127','10','172','192') ) ) 
  );
}
```

this can be improved upon a bit using the rules here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network