# $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] is fectching IP address of unknown location

Tags: php, tcp, ip, client, remote-server

I'm using $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] to keep audit of unsecured pages (without login). Somehow from last two days it's behaving bit wierd.

Ex: If I access unsecured page, IP address which is inserted is having location at least 3000 Km's from my location (In fact outside the country from which I'm accessing). 
Note: I'm finding out ip address location using URL: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Can you please help me to understand this?

Sample code is mentioned below

```
INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE (SEQUENCE_ID,IP_ADDRESS, C_DATE) VALUES (NULL,'$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]',NOW())
```

Comment: Is it the correct IP? IP geolocation services are not always reliable.

Comment: Are you sure it's not your own ip address? Are you using a reverse proxy?

Comment: @Barmar ; No IP is not correct. It's different from the one given by whatismyipaddress.com

Comment: @tlenss ; yes i'm sure, its not my own ip address. I'm not using any proxy.

Comment: Show us some code... `REMOTE_ADDR` should always contain the requesting side's IP

Comment: Are you sure the log message is for your connection, not someone coming from that other address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [suddenly $\_SERVER\['REMOTE\_ADDR'\] is started returning 10.10.10.10 php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966369/suddenly-serverremote-addr-is-started-returning-10-10-10-10-php)

Comment: @tlenss I've added MySQLi statement which i'm calling from PHP

Comment: @"Downvoter" : This Question is not a duplicate of the marked question. There are two answers mentioned , if you can clarify on second answer, it'll be very much useful.